# About Vulkan and using GLFW to abstract away Surface creation

Tags: c++, vulkan

I'm trying learn Vulkan API by writing a simple test renderer using Vulkan + GLFW in C++

So far I have

1. Made a Vulkan instance
2. Enumerated physical devices
3. Found suitable and compatible GPU
4. Created a logical device
5. Created a command pool and buffer

and right now I am trying to create a window. So far I have two pieces of code that look very similar

This one

```
 126   // X11 Window creation                                                                                                        
 127   auto display_pointer = XOpenDisplay("Vulkan App");
 128 
 129   auto default_screen = DefaultScreen(display_pointer);
 130 
 131   auto handle =
 132       XCreateSimpleWindow(display_pointer,
 133                           DefaultRootWindow(display_pointer),
 134                           20,
 135                           20,
 136                           600,
 137                           600,
 138                           1,
 139                           BlackPixel(display_pointer, default_screen),
 140                           WhitePixel(display_pointer, default_screen));
 141 
 142   XSetStandardProperties(display_pointer,
 143                          handle,
 144                          "Vulkan App Title",
 145                          "Vulkan App Title 2",
 146                          None,
 147                          nullptr,
 148                          0,
 149                          nullptr);
 150   XSelectInput(display_pointer,
 151                handle,
 152                ExposureMask | KeyPressMask | StructureNotifyMask);
 153
```

and

```
 157   // GLFW Window creation                                                                                                       
 158   GLFWwindow *glfw_window =
 159       glfwCreateWindow(1280, 720, "Vulkan App", NULL, NULL);
 160   assert(glfw_window);
 161 
 162   while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(glfw_window)) {
 163     glfwPollEvents();
 164   }
 165 
 166   glfwDestroyWindow(glfw_window);
```

And I am trying to define a function `create_surface` that'd return a `VkSurfaceKHR` object.

Going through some of the tutorials online, I see most of them define a `VkXlibSurfaceCreateInfoKHR` object to pass to `vkCreateXlibSurfaceKHR` function.

That looks like it is platform dependent and it would only work on `X11` stuff.

Which is fine in my case but I want to let `GLFW` deal with all that so I could make my application a bit more crossplatform.

The problem is I don't know how I would pass `GLFWwindow*` to `VkCreate_(GLFW ?)_SurfaceCreateInfoKHR`.

I also may be confusing Vulkan surface for something else because of this piece of code of [vulkan-tutorial.com](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Presentation/Window_surface)

```
VkWin32SurfaceCreateInfoKHR createInfo = {};
createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_WIN32_SURFACE_CREATE_INFO_KHR;
createInfo.hwnd = glfwGetWin32Window(window);
createInfo.hinstance = GetModuleHandle(nullptr);
```

I'm not too familiar with Windows but it looks like it's using platform dependent info structure and `GLFW`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not pass `GLFWwindow` to Vulkan at all. GLFW itself has Vulkan specific function `glfwCreateWindowSurface`, which gives you the `VkSurfaceKHR`.

I have GLFW implementation here for reference: https://github.com/krOoze/Hello_Triangle/blob/master/src/WSI/Glfw.h

https://vulkan-tutorial.com seems to use GLFW as well.